# How to bring focus to Show Fonts dialog (eg. in TextEdit) on a MacBook Pro keyboard?

Tags: macos, keyboard, font

I'm a quick typist and I don't want to use the mouse/trackpad unless I absolutely have no way to do something on a keyboard. It slows me down by at least 5 times.

Now, for example, TextEdit is on. I'm typing. If I want to change the font size, I can select (SHIFT-arrows) and use CMD+ and CMD- keyboard shortcuts. Works fine.

However, if I want to change the font, I can hit CMD-T to bring up the Show Fonts dialog. And that's it, the end of keyboard. I **must** move my hand and aim with the cursor to select the font.

**Is there a way to bring the focus to the Show Fonts dialog from the keyboard, without having to resort to the trackpad?**

Please keep in mind that this is about the **laptop** keyboard (MBP Retina), so it's not the full keyboard.

Please avoid answers like:

1. Why do you want to access the Show Fonts dialog from the keyboard?
2. Apple's trackpad is magnificent, you should use it, believe me it's better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you open the Show Fonts window, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F6</kbd> to bring focus to the floating Fonts window. To return focus to the window you were in, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

On a laptop, you'll also need to hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> when you press the above keyboard shortcuts unless you go to System Preferences > Keyboard and check "Use all F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys".

After you move focus to the Fonts window, you can press <kbd>Tab</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> to cycle focus through the different columns and the search field.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, CTRL+F6 will set focus to a floating window in other applications too.

For example, it can be really handy in Apple Pages word processor.

To show Inspector hit ALT-CMD-I, then CTRL-F6 to set focus on in.

From that point on you can access all fields with TAB and SHIFT-TAB.

I'm guessing that this holds true for any app with a floating window.